# How to make discord bot give me a role

Tags: python, discord

I created my own discord bot and it has all permissions on the server. I need a Python script to make it give me a role, but I don't really know how.

Comment: It would be useful to know which python library you are using to communicate with the Discord API. It's impossible to give you tips or code that works without knowing this first. You should also post the code you tried using and that didn't work so we can help you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You mentionned Python so I am going to assume you are using the discord.py library, however you should mention the library you are using in your question and include some code.

Here are your options.

1. **Using** `on_message` **Event**: You can achieve this by listening to the on_message event and checking if the message content matches a specific command (e.g., “give me admin”). Here’s an example of how you can do it:

```py
import discord
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == 'give me admin':
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name='Admin')
        await message.author.add_roles(role)

# Replace 'your_bot_token' with your actual bot token
client.run('your_bot_token')
```

2. **Using** `discord.ext.commands` **Extension**: Another approach is to use the discord.ext.commands extension, which provides a cleaner way to handle commands. Here’s an example:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def addrole(ctx, role: discord.Role, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = member or ctx.message.author
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been given the {role.name} role.")

# Replace 'your_bot_token' with your actual bot token
bot.run('your_bot_token')
```

I suggest you take a look at the discord.py library documentation here: [discordpy.readthedocs.io](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Member.add_roles).